# View property information by hovering over it in Layout Editor?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

So there used to be a way to view information about a specific property of a view/layout in the layout editor by hovering over it however it stopped working when I updated Android Studio. Is there any way to bring it back? Here's a picture so you can better understand what I'm referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: So I noticed that if I add the property to my "favorites", I can then hover over it and get information on what it does but I still haven't found a way to do it in the entire properties tab.